# What is the best place for xset commands to survive reboot?

Tags: command-line, xorg, lock-screen, startup-applications

I would like to place an xset command in one of the startup scripts.

```
xset dpms 900 0 0
```

Where would be a good place to do it? I've tried .xsessionrc but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Hi Sumek, did you notice the answer(s)?

Comment: blast from the past... by now I don't even understand my own question ...

Answer (score 2):

From `man xset`:

```
xset - user preference utility for X
```

Which might give you a hint...

#### Prevent overruling by local procedures

This kind of settings is best applied *after* possible other (local) procedures ran. If it is run to soon, it will simply be overruled afterwards by local procedures.

My suggestion would be to run it appr. 10-15 seconds after log in, Add it to Startup Applications:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && xset dpms 900 0 0"
```

Choose Dash > Startup Applications > Add the command above

#### Apply for all users

To run it equally for all users, copy the code below into an empty file, save it as `xset_command.desktop`in `/etc/xdg/autostart`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && xset dpms 900 0 0"
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=Xset command
```

#### Note

Commands to apply settings for keyboard, touch pad, screens (including `xrandr` commands), and other user specific commands are likely to "catch a cold" (be overruled) when applied too early.

The trick is then to run the command 10-15 seconds *after log in* to make sure the commands will not be overruled by other commands, or break, if they need the desktop to be fully loaded, or simply miss target.

Answer (score 1):

Use `gnome-session-properties` to create an autostart entry for your account which runs your `xset` command. The autostart entry will be created under `~/.config/autostart`.

Documentation:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html.en
- https://developer.gnome.org/autostart-spec/

Answer (score 0):

If .xsessionrc didn't work you might need to specify it on the .xinitrc file.

Comment: I recommend that you expand this answer and cite sources that backup the accuracy of this statement. [Example](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=134595)s do exist.  It would seem worth testing.